# Establishing a relationship between two models through a Concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, validation

I have the models `Province` and `User` and I need to stop a Province from being deleted if a User has that Province in it's address.

I can do `User.province` thanks to the following concern included in the model `User`:

```
module MyAddressable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    has_one     :address, as: :addressable, dependent: :destroy
    has_one     :city, through: :address
    has_one     :province, through: :city
    has_one     :zone, through: :city

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, reject_if: :reject_address, allow_destroy: true
  end
end
```

I'm trying to establish the relationship between Province and User to be able to do something like `Province.users`, in the following way:

```
has_many :users, through: :myaddresable
```

With the following result:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :myaddresable in model Province
```

Same thing if I try to define the relationship as

```
has_many :users, through: :addressable
```

Can this be done? If so, what would be the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`has_many :users, through: :addressable` doesn't work because `Province` model has no knowledge about the `Address` model.

We can build the relationship between the `Province` model and `User` model through `Address` model.

The following setup works in rails 6

**User Model**

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one     :address, as: :addressable, dependent: :destroy
  has_one     :city, through: :address
  has_one     :province, through: :city
end
```

**Province Model**

```rb
class Province < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cities

  has_many :users, through: :cities
end
```

**City Model**

```rb
class City < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :addresses

  has_many :users,
           through: :addresses,
           source: :addressable,
           source_type: 'User'

  belongs_to :province
end
```

**Address Model**

```rb
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true

  belongs_to :city
end
```

Let's assume the migrations are defined correctly as per the model associations. Now the following queries work...

```rb
irb(main): > User.first.province

DEBUG -- :   User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
DEBUG -- :   Province Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "provinces".* FROM "provinces" INNER JOIN "cities" ON "provinces"."id" = "cities"."province_id" INNER JOIN "addresses" ON "cities"."id" = "addresses"."city_id" WHERE "addresses"."addressable_id" = $1 AND "addresses"."addressable_type" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["addressable_id", 1], ["addressable_type", "User"], ["LIMIT", 1]]

irb(main): > Province.first.users

DEBUG -- :   Province Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "provinces".* FROM "provinces" ORDER BY "provinces"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
DEBUG -- :   User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "addresses" ON "users"."id" = "addresses"."addressable_id" INNER JOIN "cities" ON "addresses"."city_id" = "cities"."id" WHERE "cities"."province_id" = $1 AND "addresses"."addressable_type" = $2  [["province_id", 1], ["addressable_type", "User"]]
```

In your case, as the `MyAddressable` concern is already included in the `User` model, only the other associations and migrations need to be defined.

Hope this helps. Thank you.

Comment: That worked! Awesome! Thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to hear that! The problem was interesting to solve. Thank you too for the question. :-)